# plotting links between elements in matlab

Tags: matlab, hyperlink, plot

I'd like to visualize mufflers that i create in my program on a graph through the means of dots. The dots are supposed to represent a part of the muffler. for example:

types =

```
'straight'
'helmholtz'
'expansion'
'straight'
'contraction'
'straight'
'helmholtz'
```

this is a muffler, with all the types of elements along an axis. The thing is that the helmholtz elements are supposed to be on top of the previous element. On the same X value but Y+1. It should look like gplot but not in the circular way everyone keeps representing. If i write it down it should look like this.

Helmholtz                                                    Helmholtz
   I                                                             I
straight ---- Expansion ---- Straight ---- Contraction ----- Straight

circles would represent the text and lines would be connected like indicated. 
This is the best of what I tried but nowhere close to what i want

```
types={'straight';'helmholtz';'expansion';'straight';'contraction';'straight';'helmholtz'}
index = size(find(strcmp(types,'helmholtz')))
coords = [];
for it=1:size(types,1)-size(find(strcmp(types,'helmholtz')),1)
if strcmp(types, 'Straight')
    coords= [it, 1]
end
if strcmp(types, 'contraction')
    coords= [it, 1]
end
if strcmp(types, 'expansion')
    coords= [it, 1]
end
if strcmp(types, 'helmholtz')
    coords= [it-1,2]
end

end

axes(handles.NodePlot);
plot(coords(:), '-o');
text(coords(:,1) - 0.1, coords(:,2) + 0.1, num2str((1:amountofNodes)), 'FontSize', 14)
```

could any of you shove me in the right direction?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function plotter(handles)

    coords = zeros(length(handles.types)+sum(strcmp(handles.types,'helmholtz')),2);
    j = 0; k = 1;
    y=[]; h=0;
    for i=1:length(handles.types)
      if strcmp(handles.types{i},'helmholtz')
        coords(k,:) = [j-1,2];
        coords(k+1,:) = [coords(k-1,1),coords(k-1,2)];
        y(k-h,:) = [j-1,1];
        k = k+2;
        h=h+1;

      else
        coords(k,:) = [j,1];
        y(k-h,:)=[i-1-h,0];
        k = k+1;
        j = j+1;

      end
    end
    plot(coords(:,1),coords(:,2),'-o')
    %//adding labels

    for i=1:length(handles.types);

      text(y(i,1), y(i,2) + 1.05, [handles.types{i}], 'FontSize', 12);
```

I completely forgot to post my solution :) I'm sorry! This what it ended up becoming. It's already been expanded towards other things but like i said: you pointed me in the right direction!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is in the loop. On one end, you replace the array `coords``at each iteration instead of filling it; on the other hand, the range seems to be false (why stopping the loop before the end?).

I propose to you the following simple code:

```
coords = zeros(length(types)+sum(strcmp(types,'helmholtz')),2);
j = 0; k = 1;
for i=1:length(types)
  if strcmp(types{i},'helmholtz')
    coords(k,:) = [j-1,2]; y(k+1,:) = [j-1,1]; k = k+2;
  else
    coords(k,:) = [j,1]; k = k+1;
    j = j+1;
  end
end
plot(coords(:,1),coords(:,2),'o-')
//adding labels
j=1;
for i=1:length(coords);
  if i==1 || y(i,2)>=y(i-1,2)
    text(y(i,1), y(i,2) + 0.05, [types{j}], 'FontSize', 12);
    j = j+1;
  end
end
```

The variable `j` stores the position in the muffler, `k` the index in the array `coords`, and `i` the index in the array. I prealloc the array `coords` for speed. Then, for each element, if it matches "helmholtz", I create 2 points, one for the point itself, another which is the duplication of the previous point and is placed for plot good-looking. When you have such a configuration, you will thus see one segment from the line 1 to the line 2 of the muffler like `__|__`, and not a triangular shape like `__|\_`.
The labelling is according to this rule; I admit I don't do too much effort to vectorize the loop :).

Comment: Brilliant! thank you very much. I need to change some of it as i get this drawing but you practicaly handed the solution on a silver platter! thank you very much :) the remainder is my job!
[URL=http://s1371.photobucket.com/user/Youri_De_Groote/media/Untitled_zps08794973.png.html][IMG]http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag301/Youri_De_Groote/Untitled_zps08794973.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: I'll post my solution asap